# p:spinner is not resetting value from max to min once max value is reached

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

In PrimeFaces 6.1 `p:spinner`, the value is not resetting to the min value, once the value exceeds the max. It should be reset to min value but it is not resetting(I think that is the definition of spinner). If PrimeFaces does not provide this functionality,then how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrimeFaces source is 'open' so you can always have a look at it. In this case [spinner.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js).

Inside the spin function you'll see the following (ll. 165-167):

```
if(this.cfg.max !== undefined && newValue > this.cfg.max) {
    newValue = this.cfg.max;
}
```

As you can see, if newValue exceeds max value, newValue is set to max value (and not to min value like you want).
So PrimeFaces doesn't support this feature. Best option would be a feature request at PrimeFaces.

Another option would be to override the mentioned part of the spin function:

Create a .js file with the following content (in this case it's called spinner_adaption.js):

```
(function() {
    PrimeFaces.widget.Spinner.prototype.spin = function(dir) {
    var step = this.cfg.step * dir,
    currentValue = this.value ? this.value : 0,
    newValue = null;

    if(this.cfg.precision)
        newValue = parseFloat(this.toFixed(currentValue + step, this.cfg.precision));
    else
        newValue = parseInt(currentValue + step);

    if(this.cfg.maxlength !== undefined && newValue.toString().length > this.cfg.maxlength) {
        newValue = currentValue;
    }

    if(this.cfg.min !== undefined && newValue < this.cfg.min) {
        newValue = this.cfg.max;
    }

    if(this.cfg.max !== undefined && newValue > this.cfg.max) {
        newValue = this.cfg.min;
    }

    this.value = newValue;
    this.format();
    this.input.attr('aria-valuenow', newValue);  
    }
})();
```

It's a copy of the original function. I've only changed newValue = this.cfg.max to newValue = this.cfg.min in the mentioned 
part.

Include the script where you want to add the feature, for example:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputScript name="js/spinner_adaption.js" />
        <p:spinner id="spinner" value="1" min="1" max="3" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

However, be careful with overriding things like that when updating to a newer PrimeFaces version.

Comment: its working, also i ahve requested primeface people to add this feature.

Comment: @pabhudev And you did not reference this Q/A in PrimeFaces github issue??? Why not? Please add it there